# Batch Create Records - Creating Multiple Duplicates

Tags: apex, schedulebatch

I have a scheduled batch class that creates new custom object (Churn_Tracker__c) records for each Account on a monthly basis with 3 AggregateResult counts as part of each newly created record. However, it seems that my batch is running continuously as there are multiple duplicate records being created for every Account. Am I missing something to prevent the batch from running more than once in my code below?

```
public class MembChurnRecordsBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Asset WHERE UsageEndDate >= LAST_MONTH)]);
    }

Date PriorMonth = System.today().toStartOfMonth().addMonths(-1);
Date CurrentMonth  = System.today().toStartOfMonth();
Integer ChurnAmt;
Integer NewAmt;
Integer ActiveAmt;

    public void execute(Database.batchableContext context, Account[] scope) {

        List<Churn_Tracker__c> churnList = new List<Churn_Tracker__c>();

        Map<Id, AggregateResult> activeMemb = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([
            SELECT AccountId Id, COUNT(Id) amt1
            FROM Asset 
            WHERE AccountId = :scope AND AccountId != null AND UsageEndDate >=:CurrentMonth AND UsageEndDate != null
            GROUP BY AccountId]);

        Map<Id, AggregateResult> newMemb = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([
            SELECT AccountId Id, COUNT(Id) amt2
            FROM Asset 
            WHERE AccountId = :scope AND AccountId != null AND InstallDate >= :PriorMonth AND InstallDate != null AND InstallDate < :CurrentMonth
            GROUP BY AccountId]);            

        Map<Id, AggregateResult> churnMemb = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([
            SELECT AccountId Id, COUNT(Id) amt3
            FROM Asset 
            WHERE AccountId = :scope AND AccountId != null AND UsageEndDate >= :PriorMonth AND UsageEndDate != null AND UsageEndDate < :CurrentMonth
            GROUP BY AccountId]);

        for(Account record: scope) {
            AggregateResult activeCount = activeMemb.get(record.Id);
                if(activeCount != null) {
                    ActiveAmt = (Integer)activeCount.get('amt1');
                } else {
                    ActiveAmt = null;
                }
            AggregateResult newCount = newMemb.get(record.Id);
                if(newCount != null) {
                    NewAmt = (Integer)newCount.get('amt2');
                } else {
                    NewAmt = null;
                }
            AggregateResult churnCount = churnMemb.get(record.Id);
                if(churnCount != null) {
                    ChurnAmt = (Integer)churnCount.get('amt3');
                } else {
                    ChurnAmt = null;
                }
            if(!churnList.contains(record.Id)){
                Churn_Tracker__c ct = new Churn_Tracker__c(Account_Name__c = record.Id, Churn_Month__c = PriorMonth, Memberships_Active__c = ActiveAmt, Memberships_Added__c = NewAmt, Memberships_Removed__c = ChurnAmt);
                churnList.add(ct);
            }
            }
        insert churnList;
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc)
    {
        BatchSchedule__c b = BatchSchedule__c.getOrgDefaults();
            b.Scheduled_Id__c = system.scheduleBatch(new MembChurnRecordsBatch(),'ChurnBatch 1'+System.currentTimeMillis(),2);
        upsert b;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

if i understand correctly you want to create one Churn Tracker per month.
If so you can user 'Churn_Month__c' field to check foe existing record before creating new record for a month.